# Somar e dividir resultados na mesma query

Tags: mysql

Como resolvo essa situação?

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) as total,
SUM(bolas_agarradas+bolas_espalmadas) as defesas,
SUM(bolas_agarradas+bolas_espalmadas+gols_sofridos) as chances,
SUM(defesas / chances) as porcentual ...
```

Usar os valores somados no "AS" na mesma consulta

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso, terá que utilizar `subselects`, fiz um exemplo, 
utilizando os campos que utiliza, somente para demonstrar:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
       ,defesas
       ,chances
       ,SUM(defesas / chances) AS porcentuals   
  FROM (SELECT SUM(bolas_agarradas + bolas_espalmadas) AS defesas
              ,SUM(bolas_agarradas + bolas_espalmadas + gols_sofridos) AS chances
          FROM (SELECT 10 AS bolas_agarradas
                      ,2  AS bolas_espalmadas
                      ,20 AS gols_sofridos
                  FROM dual))
GROUP BY defesas,chances
```

Fiz um teste no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8bcb2/1) para melhor entendimento

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Diego,

Eu separaria para não dar problema com agregação, porque de primeira a gente pensa em Subquery, mas acho que assim pode chegar no mesmo resultado.

Espero que ajude!

```html
DECLARE @Total INTEGER = 0;
DECLARE @Defesa INTEGER = 0;
DECLARE @Chance INTEGER = 0;
DECLARE @Percentual DECIMAL;

SET @Total = (SELECT Count(id) total from teste);
SET @Defesa = (SELECT SUM(bolas_agarradas+bolas_espalmadas) defesa from teste);
SET @Chance = (SELECT SUM(bolas_agarradas+bolas_espalmadas+gols_sofridos) chance from teste)  ;

IF (@Chance > 0)
SET @Percentual = @Defesa/ @Chance;
-- Mostra seu resultado
SELECT @Total as Total, @Defesa as Defesa, @Chance as Chance;
```

Comment: isso não seria  em sqlserver ?

Comment: David, você esta certo, deixa eu arrumar. Rs Obrigada!